Plugin Built With Same Toolchain Is Incompatible
I'm creating a modular application. It is supposed to simply load a plugin, invoke one method and that's it. However, I'm receiving an error plugin.Open("myplugin"): plugin was built with a different version of package internal/abi which is strange considering that all packages in my mono-repo are of version go1.22.2.
The way I build the plugin go build -buildmode=plugin .
As well when I ran go version . I was presented with the following:
__debug_bin541726203: go1.22.2
myplugin: go1.22.2

I in the past have received this error, however, only when I had indeed compiled two packages with different versions of Go, that's not the case here.
I also ran go mod tidy on all packages in the mono-repo, however, with no effect on the issue.
However, once I compiled and executed the program which is supposed to load the plugin (as opposite to running it in debug mode using VScode OSS) it worked like a charm. No error.
This lead me to belive that for some reason my IDE was compiling it with a different version of Go, therefore I added at the top of the main function this line fmt.Println(runtime.Version()) which yielded go1.22.2 that made me even more puzzled.
